# Converting Console Program to Win Form

Tags: c#

I'm trying

I'm trying to convert a Console App into a Win Form, with the class being the same and the functionality being the same

Is there a direct method for converting from a console application to a windows form?

Comment: Good for you where are the problems, I see only requirements. This website is not code converting tool. Also one problem per question this is policy of SO !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new Windows Forms project. You can then copy the code inside this class and paste it into the new code behind created in the Win Forms project you just created. You will need to modify the "main" method by changing its name and remove all the Console calls. Change the parameters to take in two strings and output a boolean or a string, whichever you prefer. Then you will want to make the GUI on the form and create a button, add a click event handler to call the function presently called "main". Based on the return of the method you display a message on the form.

Comment: Why not just put it into a class library?  This is exactly the sort of scenario they're intended for.  I suppose the answer may be that if the OP has to ask this question he isn't going to be able to figure that out.

Comment: That's also a good solution and more future proof, what I did was give an answer to change the whole project to a windows forms project.